# Swipe Gesture View Controller Xcode 5.1.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer, viewcontroller

I am new to Objective-C and Xcode and I am having difficulty in changing views. I understand you can use the `UIScrollView` to swipe between image views, but I would like to simply swipe right to change views, and swipe left to return. I have `AppDelegate.h` and `AppDelegate.m` which have not been changed. `ViewController.h` and `ViewController.m` are given below:

ViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //sets up gesture recognizer
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];
    swipeRightGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender 
{
    NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
    if (touches == 2)
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
            ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

I also have `ViewController2.h` and `ViewController2.m` which I have linked to the second view in storyboard along with a gesture that I have linked to the `handleSwipeGesture` method above.

Comment: u want to swipe using two fingers ? or just using one finger ?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *oneFingerSwipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                    initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(oneFingerSwipeLeft:)] ;
    [oneFingerSwipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:oneFingerSwipeLeft];
}

- (void)oneFingerSwipeLeft:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    NSLog(@"Swiped left");
  // Add your navigation Code Here
}
```

U can use this if u want to use single finger swipe. IF u want to add two finger Swipe add your

```
NSUInteger touches = sender.numberOfTouches;
    if (touches == 2)
    {
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        {
        }
    }
```

above code in the `(void)onefingerSwipeLeft` method

Answer (score 1):

`- (IBAction)handleSwipeGesture:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender` does not need to be an IBAction since it is not hooked up to an IBOutlet. It should return `void` instead.

Additionally, instead of checking the number of touches once the gesture has already been recognized, you can make two touches a requirement for it to be recognized at all, by using the line:

```
swipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
```

Consequently, the method `-(void)handleSwipeGesture` no longer needs to take an argument, so you can remove the colon from the line where you declare the gesture recognizer.

The final code might look similar to this:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRightGesture=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeGesture)];
swipeRightGesture.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
swipeRightGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRightGesture];

...
...

- (void)handleSwipeGesture {
    ViewController2 *vc2 = [[ViewController2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController2" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:YES];
}
```